# servicestack register routes in AppHost VS decorator using RouteAttribute

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I would like to know what is the best practice with ServiceStack registering routes.

1. Define routes using Routes.Add in AppHost
2. Define routes using RouteAttiribute decorator on DTO's

I have read some where that doing it in AppHost is preferable because it de-couples route definition from DTO's.  But most of the examples I see are using the decorator pattern.

So which is better? Are there any arguments to use one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Decorating your DTOs with route attributes has become the best practice**. The release of [SerivceStack's "new API"](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) has indicated the many benefits of this but most importantly it promotes a more "succinct, typed, end-to-end client API".

By using the Route attributes in addition to marking your DTOs with one of the `IReturn`, `IReturn<T>` or `IReturnVoid` interfaces you can use the full features now offered by ServiceStack.

**Advantages**

- You can dynamically discover urls to consume endpoints based on the the DTOs alone.
- Your consuming service client code (if c#) becomes more strongly typed and it becomes trivial to change existing routes/DTOs
- Keeps the AppHost clean and slim. I’m a believe that the less code in the AppHost the better.
- code can become more testable
- works alongside adding routes in AppHost (you don't have to choose just one)
- and best of all it all just works!

For the given DTO you can use the ToUrl extension method to get the generate the route by discovery the attributes.

```
[Route("/route/{Id}/{Name}")]
public class ExampleDTO : IReturn
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

var url = new ExampleDTO() { Id = 1, Name = "Test", Value = "Foo" }.ToUrl("GET"); 
// generates  /route/1/Test?value=Foo
```

The ServiceClients will do all this under the hood. Your consuming code can become:

```
ExampleDTO response  = new JsonServiceClient(“http://api.com/)
   .Get(new ExampleDTO() { Id = 1, Name = "Test", Value = "Foo" });
```

**What about decoupling?**
I would argue that there is no big need to decouple the DTOs from the Routes. I want my fellow developers to know that the Request should not be changed without changing the route. I have seen a lot of runtime errors because I forget to update the route in the AppHost after changing a DTO.